# UITableView always in plain mode though defined otherwise in the XIB

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've created a `UITableView` using the presets using the `UITableViewController` option in the `New File` dialog. I set the style to grouped using the Interface Builder.

However, the table always shows up in `plain style`.

The data source consists of two sections with two items each and a section header. It all shows up OK, but the style is wrong. Via `NSLog` I validated that the style is really set to plain at runtime. Am I missing something?

EDIT: Here my code. As I mentioned the `NSLog` calls return the expected values.

```
@implementation EventTableView

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
   self = [super initWithStyle:style];
   return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
   [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];

   [[self navigationItem] setTitle:@"Events"];
   self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = YES;

   NSLog(@"Table view style: %@.", (self.tableView.style == UITableViewStylePlain ? @"Plain" : @"Grouped"));
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
   [super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
   [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
   // Return YES for supported orientations
   return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (_appDelegate == nil) {
       _appDelegate = (MyAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    }
    return _appDelegate.model.eventSections.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Section* eventSection = [_appDelegate.model.eventSections objectAtIndex:section];
    NSInteger result = [eventSection getCountAsInteger];
    if (eventSection != nil && result >= 0) {
       NSLog(@"Got %d rows in event section %d.", result, section);
       return result;
    } else {
       NSLog(@"Can't get event section row count. Defaulting to 0.");
       return 0;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EventCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
       cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault   reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    Section* eventSection = [_appDelegate.model.eventSections objectAtIndex:section];
    return eventSection.name;
}

#pragma mark - Table view delegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"Pressed row...");
}

@end
```

EDIT: To help things, I included a screenshot of the `Interface Builder` (style set to `group`).
[image: Interface Builder]

Comment: Show some code please. How do you instantiate the tableview in your app?

Comment: As the object comes from the XIB, I don't really instantiate anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's really crazy. I found a kind of a work around.

I added a standard `UIViewController` and implemented the protocols `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` on it.

In the XIB/NIB I removed the standard `UIView` and added a `UITableView`. I connected the view's outlets `datasource` and `delegate` to the File Owner object and the File Owner's view outlet to the `UITableView`.

Now I am able to set the style of the table to grouped. Everything works great so far. However, I don't get what's really different to using a `UITableViewController`...

Answer (score 1):

**Updated:**

Find

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame style:(UITableViewStyle)style
```

in your controller, set there `style = UITableViewStyleGrouped;` before calling to `super`

Comment: Still no :-) This init method isn't available. I check all available init methods and added a NSLog. None gets called. I guess because the object gets deserialized from the NIB/XIB.

Comment: I'm sorry, but are you sure that you are loading from that .xib file?)

Comment: And check this - is file's owner `tableView` outlet connected to your table?

Comment: Implement method `- (void) awakeFromNib` and set breakpoint there. Will debug stop there?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3856/discussion-between-spa-and-nekto)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any code somewhere that calls the `- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style` method of your view with the wrong style (which I kind of expect), 
you could rewrite your init method to

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
   self = [super initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
   return self;
}
```

First, though, you might try to ensure that you've saved your .xib in Xcode, clean and rebuild your app, so that you're sure that your changes are what's actually running on the device/simulator.

Comment: No sorry. As mentioned, I checked all available init methods and added a NSLog. None gets called. I guess because the object gets deserialized from the NIB/XIB.

Comment: Did you try changing the init method then?

Comment: And you don't have another .xib, which might be the one that gets loaded? Weird problem.